# rm -rf fails to work with digits using linux?

Tags: shell

This is my current directory which contains the following folders:

```
rpea-vd1-430: ls
rev10  rev11  rev12  rev2  rev3  rev4  rev5  rev6  rev7  rev8  rev9  Synthesis.config  Synthesis.html
```

I had used the follwoing linux command to remove the folders.

```
 rm -rf rev[1-11]
```

but my command fails if i give

```
rm -rf rev[1-9]
```

as it removes the directories which are named from rev1 to rev9; why it is not considering double digits?

Expected Output:

```
rev11  Synthesis.config  Synthesis.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is `rm -rf rev[1-9]` not considering double digits?

Why should it? You only specified one digit. The bracket expression `[..]` matches exactly one character, which has to be one of those listed inside the brackets. So `rev[1-9]` matches filenames of the format `revN`, where `N` is some digit (except `0`). Similarly, `rev[1-11]` matches exactly `rev1`, since `1` is the only character specified within the brackets, even though it's specified multiple times. It's the same as `rev[1]` or `rev1`. Similarly, `rev[1-12]` would be the same as `rev[12]`.

You could use `rev[0-9]*` to match all filenames starting with `rev`, a digit, and then anything, or using [extended globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) in Bash and ksh, `rev+([0-9])`. The subexpression `+(...)` matches at least one repetition of the pattern within the parenthesis, similarly to `(...)+` in regular expressions.

Brace expansion `{a..b}`, on the other hand, would generate strings, not match filenames, so you could use `rev{1..12}` to generate `rev1`, `rev2`, ... `rev12`. This doesn't consider if the files exist, so it would also generate `rev1`, which doesn't exist in your example.

---

Judging by the edit, you want to match (and `rm`) all files matching `rev*`, except `rev11`? The easiest way is probably to rename the exception temporarily (assuming `arev11` doesn't exist):

```
$ mv rev11 arev11
$ rm -r rev*
$ mv arev11 rev11
```

You could use brace expansion...

```
$ rm -r rev{{1..10},12}
```

(That will give errors about nonexisting names if you set the upper limit too high.)

Creating a glob that matches numbers other than 11 is a bit trickier, possibly something like this, but better double-check first:

```
$ echo rm -r rev[0-9] rev1[02-9] rev[2-9][0-9]
```

Comment: if i gave like your method it will affect my maximum folder @ilkkachu

Comment: check my expected output .@ilkkachu

Comment: @salma, I'm not exactly sure what the objective was, I took a guess.

Comment: Great Explanation am clear with my query. @ilkkachu

Answer (score 2):

Brace expansion is not numerical.

- `rev[1-9]` will expand `[1-9]` with all **character** between 1 and 9
- `rev[2468]` will expand to `rev2 rev4 rev6 rev8`
- `rev[A-Z]` will expand to `revA revB ... revZ` (providing file exists)
- `rev[1-11]` will likewise expand to all char between 1 and 1
- `rev[1-15]` will expand to all char between 1 and 1, and char 5, thus is equivalent to `rev[15]`, matching `rev1` and `rev5`

Comment: +1 for simple examples. Maybe add or replace the `rev[1-11]` with `rev[1-15]` to make it even clearer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the curly brackets and `..`:

```
rm -rf rev{1..11}
```

See the difference between  `echo rev[1-11]` and  `echo rev{1..11}`.

Comment: The questioner did ask _why_ the `[1-9]` pattern behaves as it does, not for just a quick recipe for what to do instead.

Comment: the above mentioned command not works for me @mazs